# How to trigger SVG animation when is in the viewport?

Tags: jquery, ajax, svg

I have a SVG animation in my website, it placed in center of page, and when reloading page, it automatically draw SVG, so how can i trigger it when it is in viewport?

Comment: Use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) and then trigger whatever action you need to when the SVG is intersecting the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use vanilla JS create function

```
var isInViewport = function (elem) {
var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
return (
    bounding.top >= 0 &&
    bounding.left >= 0 &&
    bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
);
```

};

after that use it like

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg1');
if (isInViewport(svg)) {
    // start animation
}
```